# Save image with matplotlib.pyplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, save

This is a very simple question but I must misunderstand the use of pyplot and figure or something else.
I'm plotting some images and would like to save them instead of just showing them and saving them by hand.
So far I've tried:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure()
plt.plot(d,c1[0:100],'b--',d,c2[0:100],'r--',d,c3[0:100],'g--',figure = fig) 
plt.ylabel("concentration")
plt.xlabel("distance")
plt.show()
plt.savefig('./Results/evol_conc_v'+str(vinit)+'a_'+str(a)+'.png')
```

The file created is blank, but the image showed was good.
The existing similar question don't seem to apply.

Comment: Could you put an executable code? `d`, `c1`, `c2`, `c3` are not defined in your code.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Get rid of the

```
plt.show()
```

or put it below the `savefig` call.

Or you do this

```
plt.show()
fig.savefig('./Results/evol_conc_v'+str(vinit)+'a_'+str(a)+'.png') # Use fig. here
```

since you already create a figure object at the beginning.